# Laravel: Too few arguments to function 0 passed and 1 expected

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am currently working on a 1 page crud for a laravel project. I had a lot of trouble to begin with, but now the last error i have is

> Too few arguments to function 0 passed and 1 expected

this happens on loading the main page of the crud. this file gives the error:
edit.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.user.update', $userEdit->id) }}">
    @method('PATCH') 
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
 
        <label for="name"> Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $userEdit->name }}" />
    </div>
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">email </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $userEdit->email }}" />
    </div>
 
   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

controller index:

```
 public function index($id)
{
    $users = User::all();
    $userEdit = User::find($id);
     return view('admin.user.index', compact('users', 'userEdit'));
}
```

yes i need $users and $userEdit, but i cant reach $userEdit on the first load of the page. normally there is also no $id in index() but i added it to try to fix it, this did not work

Comment: PLease give us ALL the error message including filename and line number and not a vague summary

Comment: you index function expects one parameter ($id), make sure while this function is being used (called by the router), the parameter is available in the URL, otherwise make it optional like ($id = 0) and update the function body accordingly (The ->find() method within an if() block)

Comment: Ohh, sorry, you said that you added the $id later. What error did you get when you did not have the $id parameter in index() method? Share a stack trace or more details of the error so that we can understand where the error is exactly.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, if i remove the $id from the index function it just gives a red bar below the code itself. the curly bar,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter in as an array with a key specifying the route's parameter name. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.user.update', ['id' => $userEdit->id]) }}">
```

Comment: not it´s necessary send array with params because function receive only id.

Answer (score 0):

you have a error in your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.user.update', $userEdit->id) }}">
     @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-group">
 
        <label for="name"> Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $userEdit->name }}" />
    </div>
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">email </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $userEdit->email }}" />
    </div>
 
   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

method not it´s `PATCH` it´s `PUT` and firts send your `CSRF`